# Joomla. How to disallow Joomla download OpenSearch xml-file?

Tags: joomla-3.x

We can enable **OpenSearch** in **Joomla** search-component to insert `links` in `<head>` section like this:

```
<link href="http://site.name/component/search/?id=45&amp;Itemid=104&amp;format=opensearch" rel="search" title="title" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" />
```

When follow this link I download `xml` with **OpenSearch** description.

I disabled this function in search-module, so there is no `links` in `<head>` sections. But! If I follow directly `http://site.name/component/search/?format=opensearch` I still download same `xml`-file.

How does it work? Where is this file created? How can I compleatly disable OpenSearch to disallow dowloading of this file?

Comment: I also have similar problem. Google bot tries to crawl that link with a 500 server error. So i disabled "OpenSearch Autodiscovery" in the search module. And then I had to tell google not to go to that link by adding Disallow: /component/search/ in robots.txt

Comment: This is true 5 years and 2 major Joomla versions later.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found was to block creating of this `xml`-file in search-component:

```
// components/com_search/views/search/view.opensearch.php
class SearchViewSearch extends JViewLegacy
{
    public function display($tpl = null)
    {
        // Return HTTP-code 404
        header( "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" );
        exit();
        ...
    }
}
```

It is not very good solution, but I don't know another way.
Now when follow this link I recieve **HTTP**-code 404.